# PHP exits with non-breaking space

Tags: php, conditional-statements

If I run this code:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $is_admin = $_SESSION['admin_5'];
    var_dump($is_admin);
    echo '<br>';
    var_dump($toggleState);
    echo '<br>';
        if ('new' == $toggleState) {
            echo 'ok<br>';
        }
?>
```

I get

```
bool(true) 
string(2) "ex",
```

but if i change the IF-line to

```
        if ('new' == $toggleState || $is_admin) {
```

it gives me no error and no output.

---

The reason for it was a non-braking space (ALT+Space in Mac Sublime Text 2). Upon copying the code here, the non-breaking space converted to an ordinary space, therefore no-one could reproduce the error.

I don't know if there's a lesson to be learned from this for antbody other than myself? Maybe better to close and delete the question?

Comment: I tried doing this with `$toggleState` set to `"ex"` and `$is_admin` set to `true` and it printed using the second if statement.

Comment: Try using `===` in place of `==`

Comment: what do you mean by "using the second IF statement"?

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bb93e49f59cef1ca882dbe1a0b2e976dc31c9019

Comment: @Konservin I mean using `'new' == $toggleState || $is_admin` as the condition.

Comment: If that is all of the code there is nothing in $_SESSION because you have not started the session.

Comment: a little hint, what does your log say?

Comment: If I use "if ($is_admin) {", it'll work. If I use "if ('new' == $toggleState) {", it'll work. If I use both ("if ('new' == $toggleState || $is_admin) {"), It'll fail

Comment: === doesn't change a thing

Comment: Sorry, it's not all of the code. Session is started, and $_SESSION['admin_5'] is true

Comment: I can't reproduce it: http://ideone.com/To8uNJ

Comment: There must be something else going on in the real code, because that `if()` line should work, and it works for both me and AbraCadaver.

Comment: Please give us your output from the php log

Comment: Thank you all for your efforts. The reason for no output was a non-breaking space. Apparently you can't copy non-breaking space to Stackoverflow, so nobody could've noticed it except for myself.